# On iOS, why changing the frame of a CALayer didn't cause an animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I have some iOS sample code that if I tap on the main view and the tap handler changes the `CALayer` object's `frame` property, the layer object will animate to its position and size.

But if I put that animation inside `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIImage *shipImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SpaceShip1.png"];
ship1 = [[CALayer alloc] init];

ship1.contents = (id) [shipImage CGImage];
ship1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);

[self.view.layer addSublayer:ship1];

ship1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200);
```

then the animation won't happen.  It will just use the `(0, 0, 300, 200)` with no animation.  Why is that and how to make it work?

Comment: First I'm not seeing a uiview animation block in your code. Second, you should animate in the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear uiview delegate methods.

Comment: There needs to be no animation code... if in the tap handler, I set the frame to `CGRectMake(200, 200, 30, 30)`, then it will animate all by itself

Comment: How would an animation take place without specifying one? If you mean a frame change,yes I understand, but an animation? Anyway, did you try moving the code in the viewDidAppear section?

Comment: @Lefteris: Animation would happen because frame is an animatable property, i.e. animation is implicit when setting the frame property. However I second your comment about trying to set the frame in viewDidAppear instead. I'm guessing at viewDidLoad the layer is not visible yet.

Comment: maybe it is because it is a `CALayer`.  For all I know right now, if that is changed in the tap handler, then the animation occurs, if in `viewDidLoad`, then it won't

Comment: @Lefteris and @Taum  Yes in fact it works... if I move the second set frame line to `viewDidAppear`, then I see the animation when starting up the app.  Why will it work there but if in `viewDidLoad`, then it won't?

Comment: Well, you should try my suggestion, as the viewDidLoad will fire before the view is rendered, so the CALayer is Not yet Visible... See this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860319/changing-frame-of-uiviews-calayer-self-view-layer-frame-appears-to-have

Comment: please see comment above... and... if I put in `viewDidAppear` the following code `ship1.frame = CGRectMake(600, 60, SHIP1_WIDTH, SHIP1_HEIGHT);
    ship1.frame = CGRectMake(600, 600, SHIP1_WIDTH, SHIP1_HEIGHT);` on the iPad, the image will not move to TOP RIGHT corner first and then to BOTTOM RIGHT.  It will move directly to BOTTOM RIGHT.

Comment: I am guessing we need to allow some delay in setting the frame for the animation to show... but can't be sure... and any other method to queue them up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several things.

First of all, the frame property is not animatable. Instead, you should be animating bounds (to change the size) and position (to move the layer).

To quote the docs:

> Note: The frame property is not directly animatable. Instead you
>   should animate the appropriate combination of the bounds, anchorPoint
>   and position properties to achieve the desired result.

Second, you have to return to the event loop after adding a layer before changing an animatable property.

When you return and the system visits the event loop, the next time you change an animatable property, it creates an animation transaction to animate that change.

Since you created a layer, set it's frame, and then changed it, all before returning, your code simply adds the layer at it's final frame.

What you should do instead is to set up the layer, install it into it's parent layer, and return. You can use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: to invoke the animation after the layer has been added:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  UIImage *shipImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SpaceShip1.png"];
  ship1 = [[CALayer alloc] init];

  ship1.contents = (id) [shipImage CGImage];
  ship1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);

  [self.view.layer addSublayer:ship1];

  [self performSelector: @selector(changeLayer)
    withObject: nil 
    afterDelay: 0.0];
}


- (void) changeLayer
{
  //Animate changes to bounds and position, not frame.
  ship1.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200);
  //Note that position is based on the center of the layer by default, so you'll 
  //need to adjust your desired position.
  ship1.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
}
```

Comment: I am quite sure `frame` causes the Implicite Animation too... coz I tried it in the tap handler and it works...

Answer (score 1):

You have specified no time delay or animation time.  So the object will be moved before it is displayed, and you won't see it in the earlier position.  You also need to return to the run loop for the display to show any animation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to trigger animations on iOS:

**1. UIView Animation**

You use a `UIView.animateWithDuration` method or other variant to directly specify that you want an animation. You can specify parameters such as duration, delay, a completion block and others.

**2. Core Animation - Implicit Animation** (DESIRED APPROACH)

As the name implies, this animation is triggered without an explicit command. In order to work though, you need to set the `CALayer` delegate, like this:

```
ship1.delegate = self;
```

All the parameters have default values until you say otherwise. For modifying these parameters, you need to call `CATransaction`:

```
[CATransition setAnimationDuration:0.2];
```

**IMPORTANT**: These `CATransaction` calls must be placed BEFORE the modifications of the layer's properties, because all animations happen asynchronous (in different runtime threads) and it will be too late for you if you put these calls after.

**3. Core Animation - Explicit Animation**

You create an `CAAnimation` (there are different `CAAnimation` subclass to choose from) and attach it to the layer:

```
CABasicAnimation *a = [CABasicAnimation alloc] init....

[ship1 addAnimation:a];
```

I hope this clarifies some doubts about the subject.